# How to set up 2 ssh tunnels?

Tags: security, networking, ssh

I need help setting up ssh tunnels.

I have ssh access to a remote machine 'R1'. There is another remote machine 'R2' which is accessible only through 'R1'. I can ssh to R2 from R1. R2 has a web-server running and I want to access it directly from my personal computer 'P'.

How would I go about setting up 2 ssh tunnels, one from P -> R1 and another from R1->R2 ? Please note, the two tunnels would have to be connected.

Is there a configuration of ssh tunnels that makes it possible to access the web-server on 'R2' through my personal computer ?

Please respond with ssh command syntax. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one SSH tunnel, like that:

```
ssh -L80:R2:80 me@R1
```

This will establish a ssh connection to R1 and setup a tunnel between the port :80 on your local machine and :80 on R2 (via R1).